# how to embed facebook video on my website and using search on my website gives results facebook videos

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I know how to embed facebook videos, but do it manually like using:

```
<object width="####" height="####" >
   <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
   <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
   <param name="movie" value="http://www.facebook.com/v/xxx" />
   <embed src="http://www.facebook.com/v/####"
          type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
          allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"
          width="####" height="####">
   </embed>
</object>
```

I'm just wondering if I have this `<input type="text" placeholder="search for videos">` on my website, how can I access all the videos on facebook? or I mean, Is there a way to access database for videos on facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will not allow you to search their entire video database. 
The best way to solve your problem is to create your own database for your website and add as many Facebook videos as possible, then allow users to search your database. I'm afraid you will have to add them all manually.